# postMessage does not send data

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am trying to send some data across two windows by using `postMessage`. However, the target window is not being informed and I cannot find the reason. Here is my code:

***origin page(localhost:8080/index.html):***

```
 <body>    
    <a onclick="popupCenter('http://localhost:58810');" 
     href="javascript:void(0);">CLICK TO OPEN POPUP</a>
    <script>
        function popupCenter(url) {
            const yoyo = window.open(url);
            yoyo.onload(function() {
                yoyo.postMessage("Hello mate", "*");
            }); 
            //setTimeout(yoyo.postMessage.bind(this,"Hello mate", "*"), 3000);
        } 
    </script>
</body>
```

***I have tried both versions of the above code: one inside comments and one as it is above. None of them works...***

***target page(localhost:58810/index.html):***

```
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
      if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost') {
        console.log("Far away");
        return;
      }
      console.log("Yes!!!", event.data);
    });
  </script>
  Hello world!!
</body>
```

The target page loads normally in a new window. However, it does not get the message sent by the origin page even if all the solutions (stackoverflow plus other sites) suggest that `postMessage` solves the cross-origin problem. Any idea why?

To make the problem **bigger**, `onload` event is never triggered. So, nothing works (neither `postMessage` nor `onload`) when there are different domains...

Comment: why are you using bind? it should work without it and it seems to be the only problem with this code.

Comment: I wish `bind` was the problem... Above, there is a version without `bind`

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper You changed more than just the `.bind` call for that, though. The problem WAS `.bind`, without a doubt. The `onload` is a separate issue entirely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the window yoyo, that's why you need postMessage, so you can't set onload on this window. The cleanest way would probably be a 2 way messaging. Something like this:

```
const messageFromChild = function(childWindow,event){
        if(event.origin === "http://localhost:58810"){ 
            childWindow.postMessage("Hello mate", "*");
        }
    }
function popupCenter(url) { 
    const yoyo = window.open(url);
    window.addEventListener('message', messageFromChild.bind(this,yoyo));
 }
```

And in target window:

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.opener.postMessage("I'm loaded!", "*");
}

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:8080') {
        console.log("Far away");
        return;
    }
    console.log("Yes!!!", event.data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you're on the right track, but setTimeout() requires a function... so it should probably look something more like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    youngFashion.postMessage("Hello mate", "*");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: `.bind` returns a function.

Comment: hmm well it doesn't return it in the expected style, because this example works when .bind does not.